# Não é possível converter implicitamente tipo "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumberable<SS_API.Model.Project>"

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, interface, controller

Não é possível converter implicitamente tipo `"System.Collections.Generic.IEnumberable<SS_API.Model.Project>" em "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult<System.Collections.Generic.Inumerable<string>>".`

De que maneira eu poderia fazer a chamada da classe no `controller` corretamente?

Interface:

```
    public interface IAcess : IDisposable
    {
        IEnumerable<Project> GetProjects();
        Project GetProject(int id);
        void AddProject(Project item);
        void DeleteProject(int id);
        void UpdateProject(Project item);
        void Save();

    }
```

Classe:

```
  public class Acess : IAcess
    {
        private Project project = new Project();
        private StreamerContext context;
        public Acess(StreamerContext streamer)
        {
           this.context = streamer;
        }
        public IEnumerable<Project> GetProjects()
        {
          

                return context.Project.ToList();
                    
        }
}
```

Controller:

```
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
        {

            var projects = from project in _acess.GetProjects()
                           select project;
            return projects;


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está tentando retornar um Tipo **Projet** enquanto sua função retorna `String`.

Ao invés de retornar o Projeto, tente retornar (caso haja) o nome dele por exemplo ou use o método `ToString()` se isso fizer sentido.

```cs
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
        {

            var projects = from project in _acess.GetProjects()
                           select project.Name;
            return projects;


        }
```

Ou

```cs
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
        {

            var projects = from project in _acess.GetProjects()
                           select project.ToString();
            return projects;


        }
```

você também pode alterar o tipo de retorno da sua Controller:

```cs
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<SS_API.Model.Project>> Get()
        {

            var projects = from project in _acess.GetProjects()
                           select project;
            return projects;


        }
```

Comment: Agradeço pela ajuda. Consegui resolver o problema deixando o código da seguinte maneira:

public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Project>> Get()
        {

            var projects = (from project in _acess.GetProjects()
                           select project).ToList();
            return projects;


        }

Comment: Legal. Essa é a mesma coisa sugerida na minha terceira opção. Note que como o retorno é do tipo IEnumerable você não precisa usar o ToList(). Provavelmente, você também não precisa usar esse `from`. Só não tinha sugerido isso antes porque não era essencial pra corrigir o erro, que é o assunto principal. Abraços!